# Call "datepicker()" more than once on one datepicker field using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have two datepicker functions called on same datepicker field.

First part of code disables all days except thursdays and sets Max selectable days to 60 and minimum selectable date to 1.

[image]
In the Second part of code I am trying to  disables dates [24/11/2022,22/12/2022,29/11/2022].But  only first part of datepicker code is getting executed and disabling dates code is not getting applied on the datepicker control.

Can't we  call more than once "datepicker()" function on the same datepicker field. Can anyone please suggest ASAP.

Comment: Any reason for adding datepicker function twice on same field? Are you unable to add all restriction in single function?

Comment: 1st part of code returns value is "day 4" which enables only thursdays. In second part of I have to disable 3 dates.I am unbale to do in single function .Hence tried to call the same function to disable those dates.